# JSON jQuery Menu Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have created a script to add a menu to a site that I am working on, it pulls the menu data from a JSON file and inserts it into the page. When the page loads, the sub-menu doesn't open when clicked :|

So I added one to the HTML file to see if there was an issue there and that one works perfectly.

I have the dev site live here https://ketchup.dev.danielcoates.co.uk/ (No longer available 30/03/17) if you need to see more of the code.

The Menu HTML

```
<div class="side-content">
  <ul class="nav-main">
    <li id="menu-0">
      <a class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#">
        <i class="si si-user"></i>
        <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">User Profile</span>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="base_pages_profile.html">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="base_pages_profile_v2.html">Profile v2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="base_pages_profile_edit.html">Profile Edit</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The Menu Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('/menu/menu.json', function(data) {

    // convert json into array
    var menu = [];
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
      for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        menu.push(v[i]);
      };
    });

    for(var i=0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      if(menu[i]['type'] == 'item') {
        $('.nav-main').append('<li id="menu-' + menu[i]['id'] + '"></li>');
        $('#menu-' + menu[i][['id']]).append('\
          <a href="' + menu[i]['link'] + '">\
            <i class="' + menu[i]['icon'] + '"></i>\
            <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">' + menu[i]['title'] + '</span>\
          </a>'
        );

      } else if(menu[i]['type'] == 'header') {
        $('.nav-main').append('<li id="menu-' + menu[i]['id'] + '"></li>');
        $('#menu-' + menu[i][['id']]).append('\
          <li class="nav-main-heading">\
            <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">' + menu[i]['title'] + '</span>\
          </li>'
        );

      } else if(menu[i]['type'] == 'submenu') {
        $('.nav-main').append('<li id="menu-' + menu[i]['id'] + '"></li>');
        $('#menu-' + menu[i][['id']]).append('\
          <a class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#">\
            <i class="' + menu[i]['icon'] + '"></i>\
            <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">' + menu[i]['title'] + '</span>\
          </a>'
        )
      } else if(menu[i]['type'] == 'submenu-item') {
        $('#menu-' + menu[i]['parent']).append('<ul><li><a href="/test">Test</a></ul>');
      };
    };
  });
});
```

The JSON

```
{
  "menu":
  [
    { "id": 1,
      "parent": 0,
      "type": "item",
      "active": false,
      "title": "Dashboard",
      "icon": "si si-speedometer",
      "link": "/dashboard"
    },
    { "id": 2,
      "parent": 0,
      "type": "header",
      "active": false,
      "title": "Pocurement",
      "icon": false,
      "link": false
    },
    { "id": 3,
      "parent": 0,
      "type": "item",
      "active": false,
      "title": "Suppliers",
      "icon": "si si-notebook",
      "link": "/suppliers"
    },
    { "id": 4,
      "parent": 0,
      "type": "item",
      "active": true,
      "title": "Duty Calculator",
      "icon": "si si-calculator",
      "link": "/app/duty_calculator"
    },
    { "id": 5,
      "parent": 0,
      "type": "header",
      "active": false,
      "title": "Products",
      "icon": false,
      "link": false
    },
    { "id": 6,
      "parent": 0,
      "type": "submenu",
      "active": false,
      "title": "Manage Products",
      "icon": "si si-tag",
      "link": "#"
    },
    { "id": 7,
      "parent": 6,
      "type": "submenu-item",
      "active": false,
      "title": "List Products",
      "icon": false,
      "link": "/products/list"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think I should clarify, there's not a issue with the menu loading into the page, but the submenu opening once loaded, the actual page is available at [https://ketchup.dev.danielcoates.co.uk/menu_test.html](https://ketchup.dev.danielcoates.co.uk/menu_test.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, tho not an elegant one :/

The problem seems to come from the functionality for the sub menu opening residing inside a function called `uiNav` inside the main `\assets\js\app.js` file. I think this is being initialised before the JSON menu is loaded.

By placing that code inside the `menu.js` call back and placing it in the `uiNav` function it solves the issue.

The final code that resides in the `app.js` file is

```
var uiNav = function() {
  $.getJSON('/menu/menu.json', function(data) {

    // convert json into array
    var menu = [];
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
      for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        menu.push(v[i]);
      };
    });

    for(var i=0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      if(menu[i]['type'] == 'item') {
        $('.nav-main').append('<li id="menu-' + menu[i]['id'] + '"></li>');
        $('#menu-' + menu[i][['id']]).append('\
          <a href="' + menu[i]['link'] + '">\
            <i class="' + menu[i]['icon'] + '"></i>\
            <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">' + menu[i]['title'] + '</span>\
          </a>'
        );

      } else if(menu[i]['type'] == 'header') {
        $('.nav-main').append('<li id="menu-' + menu[i]['id'] + '"></li>');
        $('#menu-' + menu[i][['id']]).append('\
          <li class="nav-main-heading">\
            <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">' + menu[i]['title'] + '</span>\
          </li>'
        );

      } else if(menu[i]['type'] == 'submenu') {
        $('.nav-main').append('<li id="menu-' + menu[i]['id'] + '"></li>');
        $('#menu-' + menu[i][['id']]).append('\
          <a class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#">\
            <i class="' + menu[i]['icon'] + '"></i>\
            <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">' + menu[i]['title'] + '</span>\
          </a>'
        )
      } else if(menu[i]['type'] == 'submenu-item') {
        $('#menu-' + menu[i]['parent']).append('<ul><li><a href="/test">Test</a></ul>');
      };
    };

    // When a submenu link is clicked
    jQuery('[data-toggle="nav-submenu"]').on('click', function(e){
        // Get link
        var $link = jQuery(this);

        // Get link's parent
        var $parentLi = $link.parent('li');

        if ($parentLi.hasClass('open')) { // If submenu is open, close it..
            $parentLi.removeClass('open');
        } else { // .. else if submenu is closed, close all other (same level) submenus first before open it
            $link
                .closest('ul')
                .find('> li')
                .removeClass('open');

            $parentLi
                .addClass('open');
        }

        // Remove focus from submenu link
        if ($lHtml.hasClass('no-focus')) {
            $link.blur();
        }

        return false;
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over the `value` of each array's key, instead of its `length`.

Try replacing `for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++)` by `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)` in order to loop on the whole array.

Let me know if that worked! I could have missed something :)

Comment: Changing `v.length` to `data.length` stops the JSON menu loading completely, and breaks the page even further.

The code I have above will output the menu to the page, but won't allow me to access the submenu.

Comment: Yeah I realized seconds after posting that it was not going to fix anything, sorry! Looking further into it

Comment: I found a solution, I have posted it as an answer.